# Sum element list starting from specific position VB

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to sum the elements of a list but starting at a particular position in VB?

For example if I have a list of 10 Doubles {1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} and I want to sum only the first 5 ones, or to sum only the last 5 ones.

I am aware of the .Sum() function but I didn't figure out how to change the starting/ending point.

Comment: use a loop like for example `for`?

Comment: Use the "Take" function? .Take(5) should give you the first five (or the last five depending on the sorting)

Answer (score 3):

Before using the `Sum` method, you can use `Skip` to skip over the first few list elements and the `Take` method to limit the number of elements that are to be processed.

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Double) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim first5, last5, thirdToSeventh As Double

first5 = myList.Take(5).Sum
last5 = myList.Skip(5).Sum
thirdToSeventh = myList.Skip(2).Take(5).Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what your looking for

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim l As Double() = New Double() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    'first 5
    MsgBox(sumit(l, 0, 5))
    MsgBox("done")
    '  last 5
    MsgBox(sumit(l, l.Length - 5, 5))
End Sub

 Function sumit(ByVal doublearray As Double(), ByVal startingpoint As Integer, ByVal endingpoint As Integer)
    Return Enumerable.Range(startingpoint, ((endingpoint))).Select(Function(i) doublearray(i)).Sum
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Why initialise `i` to 0 when you could just give it the value of `startingpoint` from the parameter?